# Lead conversion with a Person Account

Tags: apex, lead-conversion, person-accounts

I am trying to convert a lead to person account, in the logic we need to create the personAccount during lead conversion time. So I am using "setRelatedPersonAccountRecord", where I am passing new PersonAccount details(which are not yet inserted).

But I am getting a different error, anyone can help me here? See code details below

```
Account personAccount = new Account();
personAccount.FirstName = 'testPerson';
personAccount.LastName = 'test';
personAccount.PersonEmail = 'test@gmai.com'; 
personAccount.OwnerId = 'ownerId';
personAccount.BillingCountry = 'ITALY';
personAccount.RecordTypeId = 'recordTypeId';
insert personAccount;
Lead leadToConvert = [SELECT Id,Account_Id__c,Contact_Id__c,OwnerId,RecordTypeId FROM Lead WHERE Id = 'leadId'];

Database.LeadConvert leadConvertData = new Database.LeadConvert();
leadConvertData.setLeadId(leadToConvert.Id);
leadConvertData.setRelatedPersonAccountRecord(personAccount);
leadConvertData.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
leadConvertData.setConvertedStatus('Qualified');
Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcresults = Database.convertLead(new List<Database.LeadConvert>{leadConvertData}, true);

System.debug(lcresults);

Error: 

org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: IllegalArgumentException in: public void common.api.soap.wsdl.LeadConvert.setRelatedPersonAccountRecord(common.api.soap.Entity) when using common.api.soap.wsdl.LeadConvert(common.apex.runtime.impl.SObjectScriptRow )
```

Comment: You found what appears to be a bug in SF platform. We're able to reproduce this issue in our org and it indeed fails due to `setRelatedPersonAccountRecord` call. Please open a case with SF support. Since you already have Contact/Account in your Person Account and your lead conversion skips the creation of an Opportunity, this conversion doesn't do much. You might be able to work around this issue by setting custom fields on Person Account to indicate that a 'conversion' happened and pointing the PA record back to source Lead record.

Comment: While converting person account, company field on the lead record should be null. Can you check the lead record have company field ?

Comment: @ankaiahBandi Yes company field value is null

Comment: @identigral Thank you, i will raise a support ticket